# Regex for filename and querystring from url in 2 groups

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a mod_rewrite rule using a regular expression, and I'm a bit green as to some of the processes involved.

I believe I can do what I want if I can figure out how to get this regular expression right.

```
String is http://www.a.com/b.css?v=1234
```

I know I can get b.css?v=1234 with the regex

```
([^\/]+$)
```

What I'm looking for is it grouped so that %1 is b.css and %2 is 1234.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the url you provided:

```
http://www.a.com/b.css?v=1234
```

You can use:

```
/(\w+\.\w{3})\?v=(\d+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Kzf5o1HI_lScvSwp)

For java remember to escape backslashes to:

```
/(\\w+\\.\\w{3})\\?v=(\\d+)
```

Hope to help

Answer (score 0):

You need both a Condition and one or more Rules.

One of several ways to do it, tested on Apache 2.2 and 2.4:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} v=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*) DoSomethingWithFile_$1_AndDigits_%1?
```

- Input url: `www.yoursite.com/b.css?v=1234`
- `%1` contains `1234`
- `$1` contains `b.css`
- Rewritten url: `www.yoursite.com/DoSomethingWithFile_b.css_AndDigits_1234`